# Фикс программы сравнения множеств чисел (Си)

Tags: c, множества, дискретная-математика

Реализую программу сравнения множеств,в целом программа работает нормально до момента ввода во множество одинаковых чисел,я пытался это как то исправить но мой способ работает тольо если повторения находяться в конце множества,в середине и в начале это вызывает проблемы и ламает программу.Прошу вашей помощи.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    int input[10] = { 0 };
    int input1[10] = { 0 };
    int a;
    int b;
    int q;
    int mark = 0;
    int mark1 = 0;
    int marker=0;
    int marker1 = 0;
    printf("Enter a number of elements you want to place in first plural : ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &q);
        
        for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
        {
            if (q == input[j])
            {
                //printf("Error");
                mark=1;
                
            }

        }

        if (mark != 1)
        {
            input[i]=q;
        }

        else
        {
            mark1++;
        }
        

    }
    a -= mark1;
    printf("The plural you entered :\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        if (a == 1)
        {
            printf("{%d}", input[i]);
        }

        else
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                printf("{%d,", input[i]);
            }

            else if (i == (a - 1))
            {
                printf("%d}", input[i]);
            }

            else
            {
                printf("%d,", input[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    mark = 0;
    mark1 = 0;

    printf("\nEnter a number of elements you want to place in second plural : ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &q);

        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            if (q == input1[j])
            {
                printf("Error");
                mark = 1;

            }

        }

        if (mark != 1)
        {
            input1[i] = q;
        }

        else
        {
            mark1++;
        }


    }
    b -= mark1;


    printf("The plural you entered :\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        if (b == 1)
        {
            printf("{%d}", input1[i]);
        }

        else
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                printf("{%d,", input1[i]);
            }

            else if (i == (b - 1))
            {
                printf("%d}", input1[i]);
            }

            else
            {
                printf("%d,", input1[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            if (input[i] == input1[j])
            {
                marker++;
            }
        }

    }
    //printf("%d", marker);

    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
        {
            if (input1[i] == input[j])
            {
                marker1++;
            }
        }

    }
    //printf("%d", marker1);

    if((marker == a) && (marker1 == b))
    {
        printf("\nB=A");
    }

    else if (marker1 == b)
    {
        printf("\nB->A");
    }

    else if (marker == a)
    {
        printf("\nA->B");
    }

    else if((marker == 0) && (marker1==0))
    {
        printf("\nA!=B");
    }

    else if ((marker != a) && (marker1 != b) && (marker != 0) && (marker1!=0) )
    {
        printf("\nAB");
    }

    
}
```

Я не успел нормально описать код да и время поджимает поэтому если будут возникать вопросы - задавайте

Программа должна проверять числовые множества на их взаимное расположение, пересекаются они или нет, и одна из множеств под множеством другой A->B (A - под множество B ) B=A (В под множество А и наоборот) A!=B(множества не пересекаются) AB (множества пересекаются)

Через цикл for я считываю поочередно элементы множества в q,а потом сравнивая с элементами массива решаю что делать с ним дальше, пустить в массив или нет.Для сравнения множеств я использовал целый ряд маркеров которые выступают чем то типо мощности множества.

По моему предположению проблема заключается в том что если цифра введённая в q уже есть в массиве то ячейка массива пропускается что и создаёт проблему.

Comment: `это вызывает проблемы и ламает программу` предлагаете догадаться, что ваша программа должна делать и что за ошибки у вас возникают?

Comment: я могу обьяснить что она делает и примерно что вызывает ошибку

Comment: будьте добры, добавьте эту информацию в вопрос.

Comment: Добавил основную информацию и свои предположения

Answer (score 1):

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
  int input[10] = { 0 };
  int input1[10] = { 0 };
  int a;
  int b;
  int q;
  int mark = 0;
  int mark1 = 0;
  int marker=0;
  int marker1 = 0;
  printf("Enter a number of elements you want to place in first plural : ");
  scanf("%d", &a);
  for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
  {
    printf("\nEnter element %d ", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &q);
    
    for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
    {
      if (q == input[j])
      {
        //printf("Error");
        mark=1;
        
      }

    }

    if (mark != 1)
    {
      input[i]=q;
    }

    else
    {
      mark1++;
      mark = 0;
      i--;
      printf("\nError\n");
    }
    

  }
  //a -= mark1;
  printf("The plural you entered :\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
  {
    if (a == 1)
    {
      printf("{%d}", input[i]);
    }

    else
    {
      if (i == 0)
      {
        printf("{%d,", input[i]);
      }

      else if (i == (a - 1))
      {
        printf("%d}", input[i]);
      }

      else
      {
        printf("%d,", input[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  mark = 0;
  mark1 = 0;

  printf("\nEnter a number of elements you want to place in second plural : ");
  scanf("%d", &b);
  for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
  {
    printf("\nEnter element %d ", i + 1);
    scanf("%d", &q);

    for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
    {
      if (q == input1[j])
      {
        //printf("Error");
        mark = 1;

      }

    }

    if (mark != 1)
    {
      input1[i] = q;
    }

    else
    {
      mark1++;
      mark = 0;
      i--;
      printf("\nError\n");
    }


  }
  
  printf("The plural you entered :\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
  {
    if (b == 1)
    {
      printf("{%d}", input1[i]);
    }

    else
    {
      if (i == 0)
      {
        printf("{%d,", input1[i]);
      }

      else if (i == (b - 1))
      {
        printf("%d}", input1[i]);
      }

      else
      {
        printf("%d,", input1[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
    {
      if (input[i] == input1[j])
      {
        marker++;
      }
    }

  }
  //printf("%d", marker);

  for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
    {
      if (input1[i] == input[j])
      {
        marker1++;
      }
    }

  }
  //printf("%d", marker1);

  if((marker == a) && (marker1 == b))
  {
    printf("\nThe sets are equal ");
  }

  else if (marker1 == b)
  {
    printf("\nthe set B is a subset of the set A ");
  }

  else if (marker == a)
  {
    printf("\nthe set А is a subset of the set В ");
  }

  else if((marker == 0) && (marker1==0))
  {
    printf("\nSets do not intersect ");
  }

  else if ((marker != a) && (marker1 != b) && (marker != 0) && (marker1!=0) )
  {
    printf("\nThe sets intersect ");
  }

  
}
```

Comment: Это ответ или правка/дополнение вопроса?

Comment: ответ (код в котором работает всё как надо)